# Selenium: How to click the login button on popup?

Tags: java, apache-flex, selenium, selenium-rc, popupwindow

[image: Login popup]

The above image is of a flex made popup. I'm identifying flash objects using **FlashFireBug**(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashfirebug/) as follows(getting their object ids to use in selenium):
[image]

I'm able to enter my username and password successfully in the respective textareas using FlexUISelenium(https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/).

I wrote the following code for entering the values in the textareas:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class FlexUISeleniumTestTPF {
        private final static String BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/FlexDemo/TTDSWeb/TTDSWeb.html";
        private final static String PAGE = "http://localhost:8080/FlexDemo/TTDSWeb/TTDSWeb.html";
        private Selenium selenium;
        private FlexUISelenium flexUITester;


        public void setUp() throws Exception {
                selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore",BASE_URL);
                selenium.start();
                selenium.open(PAGE);
                selenium.windowMaximize();
                flexUITester = new FlexUISelenium(selenium, "TTDSWeb");
        }


        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
                selenium.stop();
        }
        public void clickLogin() throws InterruptedException{
            flexUITester.click("loginbut"); // This button opens popup
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            //Entering username
            flexUITester.type("sg0222186").at("unamelogin");
            //Entering password
            flexUITester.type("wag9hebbal").at("pwd");
        }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FlexUISeleniumTestTPF myTest = new FlexUISeleniumTestTPF();
    myTest.setUp();
    myTest.clickLogin();
}
```

Now, I want to click the "Log in" button. One idea which I thought is to simulate "TAB" keypress from textareas to bring focus to the button, but that won't work for me. Please help.

Comment: Please add some code/comments on what you have tried and what the results were so we can better help.

Comment: @JeffC I have edited my question to include the code. Please have a look

Comment: In your `clickLogin()` function... I don't see where you actually tried to click the login button? What have you tried and what were the results?

Comment: @JeffC I have edited my question to include the image.  I'm using FlashFirebug to get the object ids of the flash objects(like both the textareas in my case). But, I'm unable to get the id of the button and so I can't click on it using selenium

Comment: I'm not that familiar with FlexUI... there must be another way to identify the Log in button other than ID? Can you not use CSS classes, etc.? If you click on the Log in button in the inspector, doesn't it show other data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to click on the button inside the popup. This was made possible by using **Mouse-Position**(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-position/mlicednebhhgebkhhmomongffeidkdmi) and **Robot** class in Java. Below is my code:

```
                Robot r = new Robot();
                r.mouseMove(635, 210); // brings focus on login popup window, got location(x,y coordinates) from Mouse-Position chrome plugin
                // left-click mouse on the location
                r.mousePress(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                r.mouseRelease(MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                //simulating Enter key press, this automatically clicks login and submits the form
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can not click on "Log in" button . Please try sending ENTER after you successfully enter values for UserID and Password.

i.e .sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: That's not working for me either. Will try to figure out the issue somehow